# Cookies are not saved

Tags: cookies, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I use the EXT: to bring cookieconsent2 to my page in terms of EU data protection conventions up to date. But somehow I seem to EXT: to have not properly configured. Each pageview erscehint cookie confirmation with me.

Below my TS from the Constants.

```
plugin.tx_cookieconsent2 {
  settings {
    domain = http://p372493.mittwaldserver.info
    theme = dark-bottom
    path = fileadmin/cookies/
    expiryDays = 366
  }
}
```

What could be wrong? The folder under path was created by me and is located directly under the fileadmin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably set the path to `/`.

The setting has nothing to do with a file storage path, it's the [*cookie* path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path). The extension sets a cookie to save whether the user has consented, and this path indicates that the consent was only given for pages whose URL begins with that path.

So in your case, the consent was only given for pages whose URL begins with `fileadmin/cookies`, and for other pages the "accept cookies" message will still be shown.

Comment: Thx Jost, I try it this evening.

Comment: Jost, this was the missing information ans now it works very good.